# How to Standardize Outcomes in a Difference in Difference?

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am studying the effect of a treatment. I have two groups - control and treatment group and I observe them in the pre and post periods. I'm using the following regression to study the effect of the treatment.

$$y = \beta{\rm treat} + \alpha{\rm post} + \gamma{\rm treat*post} + \varepsilon$$

I want to study how this treatment effects different indices I have constructed - $\gamma$ is the outcome of interest. I'm currently struggling with deciding how to standardize these indices so I can compare how the treatment affects the magnitudes of different outcomes.

My current hunch is that I should be standardizing the variable by the mean and SD of the control group in the pre-period, so the post coefficient can capture how time effects magnitude and the coefficient on the post*treat interaction term can affect the outcome in terms of standard deviations of the control group.

A friend also suggested dividing the outcome by the number of options the index can be (they're all dummy indices) or the SD so the coefficients can be interpreted as a percent change. I'm struggling to see the intuition behind this. Dividing my outcome by the number of options will, I think, show percent changes. But I don't know how dividing it by only the SD (and not subtracting the mean of the control) will do me any favors.